# Adding a new object to ArrayList is causing memory leak?

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-leaks, javacv

Whenever I try to add a new Question to an ArrayList of Question, it leaks memory. Inside the constructor of the Question class I create five new Rectangle Objects. The interesting thing is that when I comment out the five new Rectangles in my constructor of Question class, the native memory stops leaking by at least 400 megabytes. When I run the JProfiler, the heap size remains consistent but the task manager is showing over 700 MegaByte of memory being used.

Here is the constructor of the Question Class

```
public Question(int number,int options,IplImage in,String imgname,int unit,Point orig, JsonArray cells, JsonArray rows, int avgr) throws CellsWrongDetection{
    nu  = number;
    this.imgname = imgname;
    totOpt  = options;
    this.cells = cells;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.avgr = avgr;
    optA = new Rectangle(in);
    optB = new Rectangle(in);
    optC = new Rectangle(in);
    optD = new Rectangle(in);
    optE = new Rectangle(in);
    optF = new Rectangle(in);
    tmpimgx = in;
    setoptloc();
    //drawmaps();
}
```

Here is where I add a Question in the ArrayList

```
public void addAllQuestions(int[] options,String imgname) throws CellsWrongDetection{
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        Question q=new Question(i, options[i], image, imgname, unit, orig, cells, rows, avgr);
        questions.add(q);

    }

}
```

Here is The Rectangle Class

```
public class Rectangle extends Config{
private IplImage in;
public CvPoint tl,br;
public Rectangle(IplImage in){
    this.in = in;

}
public Rectangle()
{

}


public boolean isBlack(){
    double b=0,w=0;
    for (int y = tl.y(); y < br.y(); y++) {
        for (int x = tl.x(); x < br.x(); x++) {
            if (isblackp(x,y)) b++;
            else w++;
        }
    }
    double per = (b/w)*100 ;
    return (per <= percent)?false:true;
}
/***
 * Setting Edges points
 * @param p1 top-left corner
 * @param p2 bottom-right corner
 */
public void setCorn(CvPoint p1, CvPoint p2) {
    tl = p1;
    br = p2;
}
public void setCorn(int x0,int y0,int x1,int y1){
    //System.out.println("Setting points x0= "+x0+",y0="+y0+",x1= "+x1+",y1="+y1);
    CvPoint p1 = new CvPoint(),
            p2 = new CvPoint();
    p1.x(x0);p1.y(y0);
    p2.x(x1);p2.y(y1);
    setCorn(p1, p2);
}
public String displayCorners(){
    return "TopLeft ("+tl.x()+","+tl.y()+") BottomRight ("+br.x()+","+br.y()+")";
}
public double getheight(){
    return br.x() - tl.x();
}
public double getwidth(){
    return br.y() - tl.y();
}
/*
 * Detecting if pixel is black
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isblackp(int x,int y){
    CvScalar s=cvGet2D(in,y,x);
    in.release();
    cvReleaseImage(in);
    //System.out.println( "B:"+ s.val(0) + " G:" + s.val(1) + " R:" + s.val(2));//Print values
    return (s.val(2) <= cB && s.val(0) <= cG
            && s.val(1) <= cR)?true :false;
}
```

}
EDIT:
The list gets cleared in the controller.

```
        for ( File file : filesInDirectory ) {

                if(isCancelled()){
                    view.dialog.setVisible(false);

                    return null;
                }

                view.SetNumerator(++index);
                String curimgname = file.getName();
                logger.log(Level.INFO,"Selected file "+curimgname);

                try {

                    sheet = new OmrModel(fh);
                    setProgress(0);


                    sheet.setpaths(curimgname, directory.toString());
                    setProgress(5);

                    sheet.init();
                    setProgress(10);


                    sheet.lookref("first");
                    setProgress(20);
                    sheet.scale();
                    sheet.lookref("second");
                    setProgress(25);
                    initDocs();
                    setProgress(30);

                    sheet.circle();
                    setProgress(40);

                    initQuestions(sheet.getQuestions(),sheet.getoptions(),sheet.getcols(),sheet.getrows(),sheet.avgr());

                    setProgress(50);

                    String[] results = sheet.getresults();
                    setProgress(60);

                    sheet.ClearQuestions();

                    sheet.drawgrid();
                    setProgress(70);

                    outcsv.println(curimgname+","+Arrays.toString(results));
                    setProgress(80);

                    genrslt(docs,sheet.getstudent(),"OMR", results);
                    setProgress(90);

                    //docs.push();
                    setProgress(100);
                    //movefile(file.getPath(),0);
                    System.gc();
                    System.out.println("Relaseing");
                    setProgress(100);
                    sheet.release();
                    publish(curimgname+"#"+sheet.getQrCode()+"#success");
                } catch (UnableToDetectOptions | WrongFileAttributes | UnableToLoadImage | UnableToDetectMarkers | MappingNotCorrect | WrongMarkers e1){
                    publish(curimgname+"#"+sheet.getQrCode()+"#"+e1.getMessage());
                    sheet.release();
                    //movefile(file.getPath(),-1);

                }

                catch (CouchDbException e2){
                    publish(curimgname+"#"+sheet.getQrCode()+"#Error Code 13");
                    //movefile(file.getPath(),-1);
                    sheet.release();
                } catch (RuntimeException e2){
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    publish(curimgname+"#"+sheet.getQrCode()+"#Error Code 7");
                    sheet.release();
                    //movefile(file.getPath(),-1);
                } catch (CancelException | QrFailedToDetect e1){
                    publish(curimgname+"# #Error Code"+e1.getMessage());
                    //movefile(file.getPath(),1);
                    sheet.release();
                }
                catch(OutOfMemoryError e4)
                {
                    e4.printStackTrace();   
                    sheet.release();
                }


            }
            return null;
```

Comment: What do you mean with _leaks memory_? If you create objects, they will use memory.

Comment: how is taking 500 MegaBytes of more Ram justifiable? I release the ArrayList after one complete cycle of my program finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not leaking memory; the java GC effectively deallocates unreachable (unused) objects only when you are close to running out of memory; therefore you can see 1GB in the task manager even when 10 times less that that is actually being used by alive objects.

Comment: so if i have less ram available it will use less memory? Is there anyway to solve this excessive use of memory by JVM?

Comment: Yes. Just run the program with (for example) -Xmx1024m as a command line argument (to have 1024 MB of maximum memory allocated to your VM)

Comment: I want a maximum of 500 mb allocated, will my program crash if it needs more than that?Mind you the heap is not using much memory.

Comment: You cannot have exactly 500mb, though you can have 512. Yes, it will crash if you need more than that.

Comment: Does it make any sense my program is using so much memory though it is an arraylist size of 57 which gets cleared after every run.

Comment: I don't see where would your list get "cleared" (more precisely: become unreachable) in your code. Also, the JVM allocates -Xms<something> memory when it starts, that is generally in the order of hundreds of MBs

Comment: Please see my new edited post. Would you mean by unreachable code? I clear the ArrayList in the controller.

Comment: Yes I thought you meant that you were expecting your entire list object to be garbage collected at some point. In any case, clearing it does not release the memory automatically; also Java never releases all its allocated memory to the OS so you cannot see the exact amount of allocated memory from the Task Manager (not even an approximation of it). So if your code does not go out of memory you're fine, nothing to worry.

Comment: I am assuming that list is taking all this memory hence I wanted it to be garbage collected but I guess my assumption is wrong? Is there anyway I can bring this memory down?

Comment: Just give less memory to it: -Xmx64m (or 128m, 256m etc.)